# How to save entity using MyBatis + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, persistence, mybatis

I'am using 2 framework to get and save my data (MyBatis for fetch and Hibernate for save/update/delete). What I want is to get some entity with mybatis and assign it to a new entity and save it with hibernate

Example :

I get a list of "Role" through a mybatis query.
Then I am trying to create an new entity who have that mapping :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_role")
  private Role role;
```

I am just doing a setRole with one of the Role from the list. Then I call the saveOrUpdate from hibernate. I get this exception :

**object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing**

I understand the exception but is there a solution ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This is a highly unusual architecture decision: using 2 persistence frameworks for the same objects. Can you elaborate how did you arrive to this solution? Also, do you have MyBatis and Hibernate go against the same transaction, same connection, same database?

Comment: I know that is an unusual architecture decision but mybatis have some advantage that hibernate doest not have for fetching stuff and same thing for persistence stuff with hibernate. both framework are not using the same transaction and not the same connection but the same database.

Answer (score 0):

The way how you are loading roles (via MyBatis), the Hibernate doesn't know that the roles are already in the database. Thus the exception that you see. The only way to work around it is to store roleId in your entity instead of the Role object. Alternatively, you would have to load roles via Hibernate, along with the entities that use them.

Comment: Is there any way to tell hibernate to persist the entity and just update the mapping between role and the other one without trying to persist the Role object.

Comment: @user2591626: Not that I know of.